# What might the feminine form of "mathematician" be?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-positive

With varying degrees of seriousness we have the following gendered role variants:

- Comedian / comedienne
- Master / mistress (sort of...)
- Dominator / dominatrix
- Singer / songstress
- Dude / dudette

Now suppose you *had* to produce a feminine form of the noun *mathematician*.  What would it be?  (Bonus points: Why?)

Comment: The post would be improved if the poster told us why he thought the question was interesting.  It's possible that he has a good reason, but note that the language is moving away from feminine forms for occupations.  Judi Dench is an actor.  A pilot who is a women is an aviator, not an aviatrix.  (That being said, "mathematrix" is inspired.)

Comment: It's interesting for two reasons: (1) It's funny, yet deeply rooted in language.  (2) There are presumably some rules or conventions for constructing a gender-positive form, and some interesting history on which gender-positive words were retained and which were dropped -- even if as a whole they are becoming obsolete.  I'm happy to have gotten an answer that satisfies the first reason.  Maybe I'll do some research on the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mathematrix*, because *matrix* is a math concept, so it's a bit of a pun.

You could likely use it only in jest, though.  It's too saucy to be serious.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematicienne, a trivial extension of the comedian transformation!

Comment: Then what is a male beautician?

Comment: @HotLicks beauticiomme? I dunno, gendered professional nouns are terrible. They unnecessarily imply a default gender for a job, and I'll ponder them no longer than I must.

Comment: This question is obnoxieuse.

Comment: @HotLicks: Maybe "beautician" is the neutral/masculine form, and beauticienne the female form?

Comment: @Gnawme: But would you say that if it was a _masculine_ question? ;)